# How do I read the messages printed on startup?

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 14.04 has recently started displaying a message on the purple screen that normally just displays the loading dots:

```
ot present
```

It appears to be a portion of a message. How can I read the whole thing?

Answer (score 4):

Messages printed on startup is saved to `/var/log/boot.log`. You can read them with `less` like this:

```
$ less /var/log/boot.log
```

Comment: Beat me to it. +1 , good job ! =)

Comment: Thankyou, I can see startup messages in boot.log but not this fragment...?

Comment: @jl6 Have you tried using `grep` to find the fragment? Give this a shot: `grep -E   ".*ot present.*" /var/log/boot.log`

Comment: @krt: I used vim to search the file. The message appeared again when booting today. I checked with this grep command. It's not there.